# How to read GUID from registry efficiently?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, guid

I am currently trying to read the GUID of a DLL from the Windows registry with a batch file, to be able to set references to DLLs in vbp-files automatically with NAnt. But I cannot find any efficient way to do this.

Currently I am looping through the registry with reg queries, but this takes about 30 seconds to find a single GUID.

My current batch looks something like this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "name=%1"
set "key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib"
for /f "tokens=5 delims=\" %%i in (
  'reg query "%key%"'
) do (
  for /f "tokens=3" %%j in (
    'reg query "%key%\%%i" /s 2^>nul^|findstr /iec:"%name%"'
  ) do ( 
    set GGUID=%%i 
  )
)
echo %GGUID%
```

Is there any way of doing this faster?

Comment: give an complete example please.

Comment: I edited the example. Is that ok now?

Comment: Fastest solution is: `for /f "tokens=5delims=\" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib" /s^|grep -B1 "WBEMMultiView.ocx"') do echo %%a`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your commitment. I'll stick with the other solution, as it does not require me to install grep on the computers that are supposed to run the batch. But I'll eventually check that out on my local computer to see how significant the increase in speed is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (call `script.bat "name.dll"`):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib" /s') DO (
    SET "value=%%a"
    IF "!value:%~1=!" neq "!value!" ECHO(!key!
    FOR /f "tokens=5 delims=\" %%b IN ("%%~a") DO SET "key=%%b"
)
```

Comment: Now that is awesome. Runs significantly faster and gives me all of the matches. I can work with that one. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I've been using it quite a few times. Thank you again. But currently I am trying to understand what exactly it does and why it works faster than the other one... Could you maybe explain a bit more on it, please?

Comment: Most of the time is required for `reg query`.  This query I have reduced to one. Thats all.

Comment: Why is there an opening bracket after `ECHO` in line 4 that is never being closed?

Comment: This is for a safe output to avoid "Echo is OFF.".